# MVC cannot locate views when using areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

This question appears on Stack Overflow many times but none of the accepted answers are working.  I am trying to implement areas in a project.  Even though routing is set up properly (my controllers are firing, I can step through them in the VS debugger), when the controller attempts to return a view the code fails with the infamous error I've screen snapshotted below.

Yes, my views are in the correct location and are named to match my controllers (see snapshots and code samples) and my routing seems to be set up correctly (please see code sample).  The only way I can get the view to show w/o error is to hardcode full path to the view, including the area name.  This error occurs even on a new, straight "out of the box" MVC sample app created with a single area.  Areas just don't seem to work without specifying a full path to the view.

Any help appreciated.

**My project looks like this:**

[image]

**My controller code.**  A breakpoint set in the Index method fires as expected, so the controller is being called.  The line that's commented out is the only way a view is ever returned.  As shown here, call fails with the error shown at the end of this question:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
        // return View("~/Areas/Governance/Views/ChangeDashboard/Index.cshtml");
    }
```

**Route setup**:  When I set up the area named "Governance" in VS, I got the following in a new "GovernanceAreaRegistration.cs" file:

```
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "Governance";
        }
    }
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Governance_default",
            "Governance/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

**The error**:  Even though I've followed (I think) all the rules, I get the following error when I run.  It doesn't appear that the Views subfolders of my new area are ever searched:

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming your url looks something like `<server>/Governance/ChangeDashboard` ?

Comment: <server>/ChangeDashboard fires the controller as the routing now stands (without the area name specified in the URL).  Perhaps I am just misunderstanding how areas work?  I thought that with them being registered, this allowed the correct controller to be found (which is happening), and then the controller found the matching view?  Sorry for my confusion :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL will need to contain the name of your area. It should look something like `http://<SERVERNAME>/Governance/ChangeDashboard`

Comment: Doing that already Mykroft, please see updated code in question.  I just neglected to show the override.  My apologies.

Comment: I changed my answer here to match our conversation above. I'm not sure how you were able to hit the controller as it was without including the area in the URL

Comment: It definitely does (hit the controller without the area in the URL), which is what I suppose led me down the path to confusion!  I'm seeing this behavior in two different projects (the simple one I created for this question, and the larger one I'm actually trying to revamp).  This behavior can be duplicated by just setting a breakpoint in the controller and trying the URL without the area name.  It'll break, based on my two attempts here.  Anyway, I appreciate your reply.  It works as you say in my simple app (with area in the URL) so I'll mark your reply as answer.

Comment: Yeah sorry I don't have more time right now to really dig in and figure out exactly what causes it to behave this way specifically but I'm glad I was able to get you pointed in the right direction.